# Converting a 64 bit HEX to Decimal Floating-Pointt in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So basically I have a couple of numbers that come out as HEX values in the form of "3FF0000000000000" and I want to get float values of out these, pretty much like in [here](https://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/64bit.html) So in this particular case I'd expect "20.000000000000000" as a result - which I'll later trim to only 5 decimals, but that should be easy enough.

I've tried a couple of solutions but unfortunately I know too little about conversions (and javascript aswell) to know exactly what I might be doing wrong.

The latest try looks something like this:

```
const hexToFloat64 = (hex) => {
    var int32 = [],
        float64;
    if (hex.length > 4) {
        var high = hex.substr(0, 8),
            low = hex.substr(8, 8);
        int32.push(parseInt(high, 16), parseInt(low, 16));
    }

    var uint32 = new Uint32Array(int32);
    float64 = new Float64Array(uint32.buffer);
    var returnValue = float64[0];
    return returnValue;
};
```

Much obliged!

Comment: All conversions on number data types is possible. Do you have a "spec" from origin to dest to share? ......... 64 bit hex or any hex number would likely convert to "integer". Or otherwise, not be suitable for conversion and represents a "data structure".

Comment: @GetSet I'm sorry but I'm not quite sure what you mean with a "spec from origin to dest to share". I basically have a couple of values encoded  (outside of my reach)  as HEX and I just need to interpret them as floats to display them in a view.

I had other values in the form of "43CAA727" but for those I fortunately managed to find a solution.

Comment: Ok. I understand. Representing a hex as float is probably a dead end. The hex itself is either a non-decimal number or its a data structure. I guess more context is needed on where these values are coming from?

Comment: For further "enlightened" assistance, you will need to at least partially provide how you even arrived at the hex data. In this way it can be decided whether what you see as hex, is not actually a number, but a concatenated data, as in a data structure.

Comment: In no way would it be "float" though. Float is for approximations. No one is storing definite data there.

Comment: I am making a soap call to a server which sends back an array of HEX values which I then have to interpret as described above... Nothing fancy and pretty straightforward to get the values, interpreting them however is another story

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how the numbers are being made into HEX values. I only know the expected result and the HEX value. Not really ideal, I agree.

EDIT: To clarify, I know the expected result from another small application that can read those values and display everything in a table. But then again I have no access to it's code or anything.

Comment: Then its likely a "hex string". You could convert at 2 char intervals, to see what is returned

Comment: Also my first thought was, where and have you looked at the "docs" on the return of the "soap" call? I will give you the code, to "decode" the hex. One moment please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is NOT an answer to your exact problem. It IS a solution to decode the hex. Thats all i am doing here. I have no context to solve your problem.

```
function convHexStringToString(ss) {
// ss length must be even (or 0) when passed to this function
    var s = "";
    var p;
    if (ss.length > 0) {
        if (ss.length % 2 == 0) {
            
            var l = Math.floor(ss.length / 2); // floor must never have to do work
            
            for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) { 
                var i2 = i * 2;
                if (ss.charAt(i2) != "0") {
                    p = ss.charAt(i2) + ss.charAt((i2) + 1);
                }
                else {
                    p = ss.charAt((i2) + 1);
                }
                d = parseInt(p,16);
                s += String.fromCharCode(d);
            }
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! While it did not solve my issue, it gave me a few hints on how to further think the issue. I'll also try to find out how those HEX values are being built. Again, thank you for your time!